# Basic transaction validation rules, Node accept to pool policy

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I am trying to collect all infromation about adding and verification transaction to Blockchain.

Exist 2 types : add transaction to RawMemPool and add Transations included in block.

Could any experts in this question verify that collected information is actual and correct?  Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd refrain from using the term "sidechain" because that has a special meaning which is not equivalent to competing chain tip, or "forkchain". You have an empty line in the inputs list, and extraneous space after "( " in the second to last line. Coinbase input coin is smaller or equal to reward and fees; you don't have to claim all of it for the coinbase to be valid. However, I don't think that your question works well on our platform, we work well for answering specific questions. Other mediums are better suited for open-ended requests for feedback or collaborative development.

Comment: Nice work though. :)

Comment: fixed Coinbase fees constraint. Thank you. What is the correct term for mainchain branch you can offer?

Comment: I'd call it the **"best chain"**, but I've seen other names for it such as "main chain", "canonical chain", "primary chain", and "longest chain". The other chain branch I'd call "shorter fork", or "stale fork" once it has been obsoleted. As long as both tips are at the same height, they are just two "forks", because it is unclear which one will succeed, but you can name them for recognition of course.

Comment: You would probably get more out of it, if you posted it to reddit or bitcointalk and asked for feedback. Those platforms are more suited for such a topic.

Comment: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1182712 posted on Bitcointalk Welcome anyone who can help complete this rules, will post on bitcoin wiki once  all information will be verified